# Rx js how to reuse operators

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am using Rx, and I have two clicks streams that use the same operators.
How can I extract the same portion and reuse it?

```
let gender$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(gender, 'click').map(e => e.target).filter(t => t.nodeName === "LI").map(li => li.textContent.trim())

let type$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(type, 'click').map(e => e.target).filter(t => t.nodeName === "LI").map(li => li.textContent.trim())

let combine$ = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
  gender$,
  type$
)
```

I want to extract this:

```
.map(e => e.target).filter(t => t.nodeName === "LI").map(li => li.textContent.trim())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const getTextFromLis = stream$ => stream$.map(e => e.target).filter(t => t.nodeName === "LI").map(li => li.textContent.trim());

let gender$ = getTextFromLis(Rx.Observable.fromEvent(gender, 'click'));
```

The chaining part of Rx means that calling `.map()` or `.filter()` will get you a *new stream*, which you can pass and return to/from functions.